# Dynamics CRM API not available

Tags: php, dynamics-crm, versioning

Can't seem to find an answer to this error anywhere, here's what I'm trying to do.

I'm using postman to test the API before writing code (PHP), when I do a request to to the CRM api endpoint `https://orgname.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/accounts` I keep getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "Requested API Version 'v8.2' is not available",
    "innererror": {
      "message": "Requested API Version 'v8.2' is not available",
      "type": "Microsoft.Crm.CrmHttpException",
      "stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataRoutingConvention.ValidateApiVersion(Version version, IOrganizationContext context, String versionStr)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataRoutingConvention.SelectController(ODataPath odataPath, HttpRequestMessage request)"
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Here's the postman request

Auth:

```
POST /64aa16ab-5980-47d5-a944-3f8cc9bbdfa2/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.windows.net
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache

grant_type=password&client_secret=<<secret>>&client_id=<<id>>&resource=https%3A%2F%2F<<orgname>>.crm.dynamics.com%2F&username=<<user>>&password=<<password>>
```

Endpoint:

```
GET /api/data/v8.2/accounts HTTP/1.1
Host: <<orgname>>.crm.dynamics.com
Accept: application/json
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
Authorization: Bearer <<token>>
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

A related issue I found, thinking that the version I was using was deprecated: [microsoft crm 2016 api version auto-discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883905/microsoft-crm-2016-api-version-auto-discovery/)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I was using the wrong URL,

Here's the url I should have been using `https://<<orgname>>.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.1/`

And here's where to find it:
Go into `Settings > Customization > Customizations > Developer Resources`. Your url is the one next to `Service Root URL`